Entity Inheritance and query filtering
I'm trying to achieve a very basic from SQL point of view operation but using Spring Boot and JPA
This is my Java data model:
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "default_gen")
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "contact_id"))
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="contact_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "default_gen", sequenceName = "contact_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class ContactEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "contact_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String contactType;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("person")
public class PersonEntity extends ContactEntity {

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("company")
public class CompanyEntity extends ContactEntity {

    @Column(name = "companyname")
    private String name;
}

and my repository:
public interface ContactRepository<T extends ContactEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

I'd like to be able to query the contacts table by Person or Company name, something like:
select * 
  from contacts c
 where lower(c.firstname || c.lastname) like '%smith%'
    or lower(c.companyname) like '%smith%';

so I started with this in my repository:
Page<ContactEntity> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name, PageRequest pageRequest);

but at this throws an exception:
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'name' found for type 'ContactEntity'

is there a way to query the contacts table using properties that do not exist on Contact POJO?

u should use different Repostiory classes for different entities - then you won't have this issue

The point is my goal is to list all entity types that match the name criterion.
With different repoeitories I'd have to make a new repoeitory every time I'll extend the model - and then somehow join the results into a single colletcion.

I managed to solve it using a custom query
@Query(value = """
        SELECT c
          FROM ContactEntity c
         WHERE LOWER(c.name) LIKE %:name%
            OR LOWER(CONCAT(c.firstName, c.lastName)) LIKE %:name%
         ORDER by id""")
Page<ContactEntity> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(@Param("name") String name, PageRequest pageRequest);

